# How does make build an executable file from a C source file when the implicit rule says nothing about executables?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, executable

From the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) I understand there is an implicit rule for `.c` programs:

> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’

When, for example, I type `make helloworld` and only have a `helloworld.c` file in my working directory, I see the following is executed:

`cc helloworld.c -o helloworld`

If I type `make -d helloworld` I see that at no time does `make` look for an intermediate `helloworld.o` file.

In the end, I don't see a `.o` file in my directory, only the executable file. How does `make` build the executable from the source file if the implicit rule for `.c` program says it should build a `.o` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different implicit rules in the built-in database. And make never has objections if the pattern rules are ambiguous, as it always sets the priorities for them.

In this case, the rules `%: %.o` and `%.o: %.c` are superseded by the rule `%: %.c` (because one step is better than two ;-)), which does compiling into an executable without ever creating object files (yes, gcc can do this).

However, you can force .o creation with this command:

```
make helloworld.o helloworld
```

Here, after helloworld.o successfully created, make will prefer `%: %.o` rule over `%: %.c`, so it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are many implicit rules. In this case there is one for building an executable directly from a C file. In your output from `make -d helloworld` you should see something like:

> Trying implicit prerequisite 'helloworld.c'.
>
> Found an implicit rule for 'helloworld'.

Comment: Thank you! You're right. I do get those lines when running `make -d`